# Need help on deletion of linked list. Linked list is only deleting the first item

Tags: c, linked-list

```
printf("Fault id to delete? ");
scanf("%d", &compare);

if (list == NULL)
    printf("List is empty");
else if (compare = list->faultid)

    list = list->next;
else
{
    temp = list;
    while (temp->faultid != compare)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    prev->next = prev->next->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

here is my deletion part it only deletes the first item from the linked list but not other items.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to delete the entire list? The code you posted searches for a particular item, removes it from the list and frees it, but it has a couple of bugs. (1) If the item is the first on the list, it is effectively removed but not freed. (2) If the item is not first on the list (and the list is not empty), the code does not check whether the item is on the list at all; it should check when the end of the list is reached without finding the item and not attempt to remove anything in that case.

Comment: Another bug is the use of the assignment operator `=` when the equality comparison operator should have been used: `else if (compare = list->faultid)` should be `else if (compare == list->faultid)`.

Comment: sentence correction

Comment: You may find the example in [Singly Linked List](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The current code seems to be looking for a particular item on the list, and removes and frees the item. However, it has some bugs:

1. The wrong operator has been used in a test for equality:

   ```
   else if (compare = list->faultid)
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   else if (compare == list->faultid)
   ```
2. If the item is the first on the list, the item is removed from the list (by advancing the start of list pointer to the next item), but the item is not freed.
3. If the item is not the first on the list (and the list is not empty), the code loops to look for the item on the list, but does not check that the item is actually on the list. That might not always be a bug if you are *sure* the item is on the list, but in any case, it is safer to check that the end of the list has not been reached during the search for the item.

Here is some code to search for an item on the list, remove it and free it.

```
prev = NULL;
temp = list;
while (temp != NULL && temp->faultid != compare)
{
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
}
if (temp != NULL)
{
    /* item found - remove it */
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        /* item was found at start of list */
        list = temp->next;
    }
    else
    {
        /* item was found not at start of list */
        prev->next = temp->next;
    }
    /* free the found item */
    free(item);
}
```

The question mentions that it only removes the first item. I take that to mean that all matching items should be removed from the list. Here is some code to remove and free all matching items on the list:

```
prev = NULL;
temp = list;
while (temp != NULL)
{
    if (temp->faultid == compare)
    {
        /* item found - remove it */
        if (prev == NULL)
        {
            /* item was found at start of list */
            list = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = list;
        }
        else
        {
            /* item was found not at start of list */
            prev->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            temp = prev->next;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

The above can be simplified by using a pointer to a pointer to the list node:

```
struct mylist **pre = &list;
struct mylist *temp;
while ((temp = *pre) != NULL)
{
    if (temp->faultid == compare)
    {
        /* item found - remove it */
        *pre = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        pre = &temp->next;
    }
}
```

In the above code, `struct mylist` represents the type of the list node. You should change that to the *actual* type of your list node.